# How to rotate Adview from Admob in Andengine?

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, andengine, android-view

I have the following code to display ads from Admob on top of my game.

The problem Lies here. My game is in Landscape mode, but I want the ads to come in Potrait mode on top.

Present Situation http://postimg.org/image/z4dc271x9/

Final Output Required http://postimg.org/image/83d7afe9h/

What should I change in my code?

```
 this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);

   this.mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(this.mEngine,this);
   final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

   //Creating the banner view.
   AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "MY_ID_HERE");
   adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
  final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


   final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

   final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);


   frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView,surfaceViewLayoutParams);
   frameLayout.addView(adView,adViewLayoutParams);

   this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Add two more lines after creating your adView...**

//Creating the banner view.

```
 AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "MY_ID_HERE");
   adView.setRotation(-90.0f);
   adView.setX(-600.0f); // Adjust the value as per your requirement.
```

**Then remove "Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL" in the following line :**

```
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```